# Cannot find org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce for CDH

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am using Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.8.2 and HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.9.0.

I tried to add reference.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat;
```

But I am getting an error.

```
The import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce cannot be resolved
```

This is my pom.xml  .

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.myorg.horizon</groupId>
<artifactId>loadHBase</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId> 
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId> 
      <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.0</version> 
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0-cdh5.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0-cdh5.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Am I missing reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with CDH maven dependencies. I created a regular Java project and manually added JARs present in my /usr/lib/hbase directory and got rid of this error.